# Convert Wavefont File to .ifc with additonal meta data

Tags: ios, wavefront, ifc

We are building a building survey app using 3d .obj/.mtl files on the ipad and wish to convert them to BIM .ifc.

We want to add additonal layers of data to the .obj/.mtl (eg. walls, floors, windows, doors, lightfittings etc) and seek advice on how this can be included when converting to .ifc

There is plenty of stuff on .ifc to .obj but not the other way round when wanting to add relevant information. your help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about [Wavefront .obj file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to convert these files? Or are you looking to do this programmatically?

Comment: We are looking to do it programmatically. obj and mtl only store coordinates and photo values. we want to attach metadata such as floors and walls to sync in with BIM ifc

Comment: So now that we all know you would like to do this programmatically.  What error do you need help with? We need sample code you have written to demostrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sketchup pro.

Import .obj (might need plugin for this) and export your .ifc?